# Modifying existing route entry in linux

Tags: linux, routing

what is the command to modify metric of an existing route entry in linux?
I am able to change gateway of an existing entry using "ip route  change" command as below but not  able to change metrics. Is there any other command for that?

```
route –n
40.2.2.0        30.1.3.2        255.255.255.0   eth2

ip route change 40.2.2.0/24 via 30.1.2.2

route -n
40.2.2.0        30.1.2.2        255.255.255.0   eth1
```

Comment: Here is a website page that has the commands to edit IP addresses using the ifconfig command. I don't know all the commands off the top of my head, but hopefully this page will help you. http://www.tecmint.com/ifconfig-command-examples/

Comment: Delete the route and then add it again, unless they've since fixed http://lkml.iu.edu/hypermail/linux/net/0504.3/0017.html

Comment: I don't understand what your commands above are trying to show. In one you have a route on `eth2` and the other on `eth1`. They're totally different.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As noted in a [comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/245208/modifying-existing-route-entry-in-linux/245235#comment421232_245208) to the question, quoting a [message](http://lkml.iu.edu/hypermail/linux/net/0504.3/0017.html) on the linux-net mailing list: "The metric/priority cannot be changed [...] This is a limitation of the current protocol [...]."
The only way is to delete the route and add a new one.

This is done using the `route` command, example:

```
sudo route add -net default gw 10.10.0.1 netmask 0.0.0.0 dev wlan0 metric 1
```

[Debian manpage for the route command](https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/net-tools/route.8.en.html)

Comment: The question wasn't how to add a route with a given metric; OP wanted to change the metric on an existing route (without deleting and re-adding the route).

Comment: Obviously you haven't read the comment in the question which links to the email showing that the metric can not be changed: `The metric/priority cannot be changed [...] This is a limitation of the current protocol[...]`. The only way is to delete the route and add a new one.

Comment: I know the metric can't be changed. Your answer still doesn't answer the question -- maybe point out, in the answer, that the metric can only be changed by deleting and re-adding the route?

Answer (score 33):

(Combining various comments into an answer)

Currently, it is not possible to modify a route's metric. As a [2005 message on LKML states](http://lkml.iu.edu/hypermail/linux/net/0504.3/0017.html):

> [...] The metric/priority cannot be changed because we do not have separate fields for the fields to match and the new values so if you specify a metric the entry simply won't be found and the request fails with ENOENT because NLM_F_CREATE is not specified. This is a limitation of the current protocol and it might be a good idea to to change this, however it's non trivial [...]

This seems to apply both to `ip route change` and `ip route replace` - the former results in an error for me, while the latter creates an additional route as advertised (its man page states that `replace` will replace *or* create a route). This is consistent with the kernel responding with ENOENT, and `ip route replace` following up with a route creation request.

---

So, the solution is to delete the existing route and add a new one.
e.g.

```
ip route del 40.2.2.0/24 via 30.1.2.2
ip route add 40.2.2.0/24 via 30.1.2.2 metric 1234
```

Comment: yes, got bitten by this problem this past few months... as Brian Cantrill keeps saying about Linux: It's an evolving thing with NIH (not invented here) syndrome...

Comment: @Hvisage can you elaborate? Is there any tool which allows to change the metric without having to remove it?

Comment: @Braiam That is a negative, as in: *NO* such tool exists.  as per the answer. If you refer to my Bryan Cantrill quotes, it was somewhere I believe in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wTVfAMRj-7E

Answer (score 21):

[`ifmetric`](http://0pointer.de/lennart/projects/ifmetric/) will allow you to change your route metric on the fly, given the interface the routes you want to change are going through.

#### Usage

```
ifmetric <iface> [<metric>]
```

For example, use `ifmetric tun0 12` to change the metric to 12 for all routes going through `tun0`.

Answer (score 5):

It can be done by nmcli as mentioned below:-

```
nmcli connection modify ACTUAL_CONNECTION_NAME ipv4.route-metric 100
nmcli connection up ACTUAL_CONNECTION_NAME
```

Comment: This solution worked best for making this change persistent with future connections on my wwan0 link.