# Why does `ip route replace` add a duplicate new route?

Tags: ip, route

These are my `ip route`s,

```
default via 172.16.42.1 dev ens5 proto dhcp src 172.16.42.248 metric 100 
default via 172.16.42.1 dev ens3 proto dhcp src 172.16.42.79 metric 100 
default via 10.2.64.1 dev ens4 proto dhcp src 10.2.69.64 metric 100
```

I used `ip route replace` with the intent to lower the metric and raise the priority, like this,

```bash
sudo ip route replace default via 10.2.64.1 dev ens4 metric 90
```

However, this didn't replace the route, it added to it, now I've got,

```
default via 10.2.64.1 dev ens4 metric 90 
default via 172.16.42.1 dev ens5 proto dhcp src 172.16.42.248 metric 100 
default via 172.16.42.1 dev ens3 proto dhcp src 172.16.42.79 metric 100 
default via 10.2.64.1 dev ens4 proto dhcp src 10.2.69.64 metric 100
```

Is there anyway to change the metric on this line,

```
default via 10.2.64.1 dev ens4 proto dhcp src 10.2.69.64 metric 100
```

Without adding a new route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is that you can't, for [reasons found here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/457993/3285)

Currently you have delete first, and then add.

```
sudo ip route del 10.2.64.1 via 30.1.2.2
sudo ip route replace default via 10.2.64.1 dev ens4 metric 90
```